# Why does lower integer represent higher priority in scheduling literature?

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

I'm studying Real Time Systems, and in the textbook most of the focus is on scheduling algorithms. (Textbook: Real-Time Systems by Jane W. S. Liu)

In the algorithms that involve priorities, it is said that smaller integer represents higher priority (e.g. a process with priority 1 has more priority than one with 3). Then, in the subsequent discussions, there are terms involved like: "Let Pi be a process with a higher priority..." On such occurrences, I get confused whether higher priority means actually higher priority or larger integer. In most of the cases it means the former, however sometimes I've to guess that from the context, which is a bit time consuming.

As far as I know, all algorithms will work well with slight modifications if larger integers represented higher priority, and that would avoid confusion. So my question is: 
Is there any reason, apart from conventional / historical one, for using smaller integer for denoting higher priority? If not, why not amend it and avoid confusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has always troubled me too.  The problem is with the origins of the English word and the difference between [ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) ("first", "second", "third", ...) and [cardinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) (the numbers you use to count things).

In schedulers we use the word *priority* in the sense of:

> the right to take precedence or to proceed before others[1]

It came into English from Norman French after the [Norman conquest of England](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_England) in 1066.  It came into Norman French from the Latin word *prior*, which (in English) means

> existing or coming before in time, *order*, or importance[1]

I added the emphasis on the word *order* to emphasize that we are using the word in the sense that requires we use *ordinal* numbers.  So you should think of it in terms of a medieval court hierarchy.  The king is seated at the dinner table *first* because he has the *highest* rank.  The prince (etymology: via Norman French from Latin *princeps*, which means "first citizen"[2]) is seated *second* because he has the next highest rank.  Then the dukes are seated *third* because they have the next highest rank.  And so on.  The knights are seated *last* because they have the lowest rank.  (The common folk with no title don't get seated at all because they have no rank at all.)

[1] This is from the definition from Google.  I think they may have gotten it from Oxford English Dictionary.
[2]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_and_noble_ranks

Comment: Typically, the king, having the highest rank, is seated *last*. The lower ranks arrive first and wait for him; the king waits for no-one.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm just a simple North American, your sophisticated old-world ways frighten and confuse me.  Would it work better if I said the king gets _served_ his dinner first (after he is seated)?

Comment: That would work, yes. :-)

Comment: That's a good explanation. But then, in CS we're using numbers, whose default interpretation is cardinal, which causes the confusion. Can't we all decide to use higher numbers for higher priority? That'll make lives of many people a lot simpler, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no general agreement on whether 1 is the highest or lowest priority.Some systems use low numbers to represent low priority ; others use low numbers for high priority.

*Operating System Concepts*, by Abraham Silberschatz and James Peterson

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! Is your answer a quote from the book you mention? If so, please edit it to make this clear: add `>` before the quote to indent it, and give the full title of the book. Thanks!

Comment: But what is the reason behind such disagreement? Why would anyone want to use low numbers to represent high priority? That is my question.

Comment: 1=> First . This means , while making Gantt Chart or giving CPU time slice , the Process with   priority->1(First),should be given time slice First.

Comment: Fun fact: Linux uses *both*. In userland `-20` is the most priority and `19` is the least priority, but in kernelland they get mapped to `40` for most priority and `1` for least priority. See `getpriority(2)`

Answer (score 1):

I've always assumed it was related to time. Most people agree that time travels in one direction, and assign larger numbers as it continues.

This works whether you are referring to "which task has the earliest deadline" or "which task was inserted into the priority queue first" (which is often phrased as "which task has been waiting longer", but it doesn't make sense to constantly increment a counter for that, it is derived from the current time and the start time).

Even in the presence of more complex scheduling algorithms, it still makes sense to have all the numbers pointing the same way.